# Данные из формы передавать методом GET

Tags: node.js

Прошу помощи в освоении некоторых методов для работы с сетью.

1.Как получить исходный код страницы? 
Делаю `get` запрос на сайт гугла:

```
const http = require('http');
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Пишет.

> Got error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL
>   Собственно, в чём ошибка? Пример взят из [офф доки](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).

2.Нашёл ещё один способ. Взял код [отсюда](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).
 Единственное, что изменил:

```
const options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',   //или GET
};
```

Прошу пояснить, что означает `res.statusCode` (где взять значения кодов статусов?), 
Для чего в конце примера написано: `req.end();` ?

З. На одном сайте нашёл пример простенького приложения. Выводится форма для ввода данных и  данные отправляются на эту же страницу методом `POST`. Код "принятия" данных выглядит так:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    const pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    let postData = '';
    req.setEncoding('utf8'); 

    req.addListener('data', function(postDataChunk) {
    postData += postDataChunk;
        console.log('Новые данные: ' + postDataChunk);
    });

    req.addListener('end', function() {
        const post = require('querystring').parse(postData);
        // операции с данными
    });
}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');
```

Вопрос: если бы данные из формы передавались методом `GET`, как нужно было бы изменить данный код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) все прекрасно работает (причем не на примерах уровня 'hello node.js', какая у вас версия ноды? Второй вариант работает?)

А получить содержимое примерно так:

```
//.....
function( response ){
  var pageHtml = '';
  response
    .on('data', function( chunk ){ pageHtml += chunk }
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log( pageHtml );
      // pageHtml - requested page content
    })
}
//.....
```

2) statusCode - код ответа на ваш HTTP запрос. Найти коды статусов можно в гугле

###### ( [для ленивых](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP) ).

3)

```
var url = require('url');
http.createServer(function( req, res ) {
   var GET = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
   // ....
})
```

###### PS: Небольшое пожелание - не задавай несколько разноплановых вопросов в одном, возможно у кого-то, например, возникнет вопрос парсинга GET параметров и он не сможет найти ответ, т.к, согласись - заголовок вопроса никак этому не способствует

###### PPS: На правах троллинга и провокации - верните <small> и <strike> :P

Comment: Версия ноды 0.6.18. Второй вариант работает. 

Коды статусов я не искал, т.к. думал они специфичны для ноды, а с http на других япах я практически не работал(

3) Как же я сам не додумался(!?!) Но что будет, если гет запрос был выполнен через ajax? URL адрес страницы может не измениться, что делать в данном случае?

"PS: Небольшое пожелание - не задавай несколько разноплановых вопросов в одном", хорошо) Просто я привык к другим форматам форумов, на которых приветствовалось задавать все нужные вопросы касающиеся данной тематики в одной теме..

Comment: @LightStock - так офф дока 0.8+. Либо обновитесь до последней стабильной версии, либо читайте актуальную доку для вашей версии ***http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.18/api/***.

"URL адрес страницы может не измениться" - не тупи. Если ты отправляешь ajax GET запрос, при передаче параметров - URL страницы изменяется, даже если код выглядит примерно так:

     $.get('', {p1 : '...', p2 : '...'}, function(){/*...*/})

По факту будет запрошен url: 'http://site/?p1=...&p2=...', так что ничего не делать :)

PS: Вопросы не совсем одной тематики, пример я привел

Comment: Можешь ответить на "Для чего в конце примера написано: req.end(); ?" ко второму вопросу?

З.Ы. спасибо, в последнее время часто выручаешь)

Comment: `req.end` однозначно достоен отдельного вопроса.

Если коротко, то node.js использует http 1.1 и chunked transfer encoding, соответственно в ноде нет content-length и т.д.( что избавляет от необходимости буферизировать весь html перед ответом клиенту ), req.end - нужен для того, что-бы сервер мог "сообщить браузеру" о том, что "ему больше нечего сказать" :) ( объяснил настолько просто и коротко, насколько это возможно )

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: Кушай с булочкой

Comment: Булочек нету(